# ReactJS NodeJS CORS Request Not Succeeded calling NodeJS https API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux

My reactjs website runs on https and my NodeJS server is https but I got error calling the NodeJS api from reactjs website. Both ReactJS website and NodeJS api deployed on the same linux VPS server, my database is on a remote but the connection is fine as I am not getting database connection error but i got cors errors like below:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8184/api/v1/signin. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

My NodeJS that started the https server enable cors and it allowed cross origin. See my NodeJS

```
const cors = require('cors')({
   origin: 'https://mydomaindotcom'
});


const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT,PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, ');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
// Error logger
app.use(logger('dev', {
    skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 },
    stream: fileWriter
}))
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors);
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use("/api/v1", routes);
```

In my ReactJS package.json file i have my domain as homepage like below:

```
"homepage": "https://mydomain",
"Hostname": "https://mydomain",
```

Please help on this cors errors, it has taken enough sweat on my face.

Comment: This has nothing to do with permissions - the code simply can't find the file on the path it's looking for it in.  And CORS issues are not really related to SSL.  It's unclear where the .pem is and where your code is.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I want to be sure it is permission error. The code is in a directory on the /home directory in linux i.e /home/nodeapp/ and the .pem files in in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem . In Nodejs, when you require path and use path like this path.basename('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem') this will definitely gets you the privkey.pem file. i pass this path to a variable but nodejs couldn't find it, even when i copied the .pem file to the root directory, nodejs still don't find them.

Comment: This is the NodeJS code : the path is working if i open it with nano editor.

const keyFile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem';
const certFile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem';
const caFile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/chain.pem';

const sslServer = http.createServer(
{
   key: fs.readFileSync(path.basename(keyFile)),
   cert: fs.readFileSync(path.basename(certFile)),
   ca: fs.readFileSync(path.basename(caFile))
}, app
);

sslServer.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=> console.log('Secure HTTP server started on port ${process.env.PORT}'));

Comment: I was able to solve the and I can start the NodeJS server but I am having cors errors "request not succeeded". Please can you help –

Comment: No code in comments, please. [Edit] your question to add code, like I did from your comment.